# Liferay 6.2 is not deploying my jar files

Tags: maven, liferay

I need to modify and deploy some liferay modules that I didn't write. The original developer is not with the company anymore and there's almost no documentation on the code. The project is structured differently to the liferay projects I'm familiar with, so I'm struggling with the deployment.

It's a maven project with a number of modules, and when I build it generates multiple jar files. When I copy one of those jar files to my local deployment folder Liferay prints something like:

**13:07:23,201 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][ModuleAutoDeployListener:70] Module for /Users/ali/LIFERAY/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp14/deploy/com.monator.ehp.routes.servicemix.moci-1.6.1.jar copied successfully. Deployment will start in a few seconds.**

... and then nothing. If I check the liferay/data/osgi/modules/ directory I do see the jar file is present there, however when I test the behaviour I do not see my changes reflected, even after restarting the tomcat server.

We're running Liferay 6.2 ee sp14 with tomcat and postgres. I believe the modules in question are osgi modules, but I don't think that changes the deployment method?

EDIT: This is the main project pom file, running "mvn install" in the same directory does not create a war file, but does create multiple individual jar files in the various child module folders:

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.monator.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>monator-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.monator.clients.moh</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-routes</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Camel Route Project Parent</name>

    <scm>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/monator/ehealth-portal-camel-routes.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/monator/ehealth-portal-camel-routes.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/monator/ehealth-portal-camel-routes.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <modules>
        <module>servicemix.routes.parent</module>
        <module>liferay.routes.parent</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <camel.version>2.13.2</camel.version>
        <osgi.export.package></osgi.export.package>
        <osgi.import.package>*</osgi.import.package>
        <osgi.bundle.symbolic.name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</osgi.bundle.symbolic.name>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${osgi.bundle.symbolic.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${osgi.bundle.symbolic.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>${osgi.export.package}</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>${osgi.import.package}</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <!-- Dependencies only declared for IDE support -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <!-- Since we're using Maven 3, this is necessary. -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 6.x can deploy war files, not jars!

Maybe your maven projects builds many jars for then build a war file?

Better if you post the pom.xml and the internet crew try to understand the mistery..

EDIT:

This project build osgi jars for **Apache Camel** to create some custom routes! https://camel.apache.org/ , there are not Liferay modules!

(Maybe Liferay plays as Camel consumer/producer?)

Comment: Thank you Daniele, I have edited the original post with the parent pom file. Running mvn install does not create a single war file (the way it does for the liferay projects I am used to working with), but creates multiple jar files in various child folders. I haven't figured out a way to package them into a single war file.

Comment: Check the new response.. @SolS

Comment: I see. I'm looking into Camel now, looks like this might be much harder to solve than I'd hoped. I'm pretty sure some of the modules are setting up liferay message bus routes though, wouldn't those need to be deployed to liferay?

Comment: @SolS Maybe, if it was true then some jar generated has to placed in tomcat/lib/ext folder to be loaded as global liferay lib. You have to find out which liferay plugin connect to Camel  to prove it.